# Perl Open and Flock timeout

Tags: perl, flock

Does the "[open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)" function in Perl automatically checks whether a file is locked and wait for it to be unlocked? if so, how long does it wait or how can I control that period of time?

I have 5 forked processes appending data to the same file. Each forked process basically opens the file and then flocks it. It then appends its data and closes the file handler to unlock the file so that the other forked processes can use it.

Everything works as expected, but I'm afraid that the open command might timeout if one of the forked processes takes too long to complete its task.

Comment: See [flock](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/flock.html) for an example, including the note at the very end about `fork` calls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`flock`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=flock&sektion=2&manpath=SuSE+Linux%2Fi386+11.3) only prevents locks from being obtained using `flock`; it doesn't prevent a file from being opened, read, modified or deleted.

`flock` without the `LOCK_NB` flag will block until a lock can be obtained, or until interrupted by a signal.

`flock` with the `LOCK_NB` flag will return immediately.

- If `flock` was able to obtain a lock, it will return true.
- If `flock` was unable to obtain a lock, it will return false, and `errno` will be set.

  - `$!{EINTR}` indicates that operation was interrupted by a signal.
  - `$!{EWOULDBLOCK}` indicates that waiting would be required but `LOCK_NB` was specified.

Comment: I see. How can I make a forked process check if there is a lock on a file and then wait until the file is unlock so that it writes its data into the file?

Comment: Nevermind, you just answered my question. I just have a doubt now, how long would flock wait before it gives up waiting for a file to be unlocked?

Comment: I've clearly specified under which conditions `flock` returns in my answer. Without `LOCK_NB`, it will wait until interrupted by a signal.

Answer (score 2):

No, `open` does not interact with locks at all. Locking a file just prevents others from locking it, nothing else.